# Update Router query without firing page change event in Next JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

I want to change a URL query for the current page in Next JS without triggering the page change event. **My use case is to simply remember the week being viewed in a calendar, similar to Google Calendar**. Here's what I've tried:

```js
import Calendar from '../components/Calendar'
import { formatDate } from '../utils'

class CalendarDashboardPage extends React.Component {
  refreshQuery(date) {
    const { pathname, asPath } = this.props.router
    const d = formatDate(date) // YYYY-MM-DD
    this.props.router.push(pathname, asPath, { query: { d }, shallow: true })
  }

  render() {
    return <Calendar onDateChange={this.refreshQuery) />
  }
}

export default withRouter(CalendarDashboardPage)
```

This almost seems to work OK, but because `this.props.router.push` triggers a page change in Next, it causes the page loading bar that I'm using ([nprogress](https://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/)) to appear on screen. I've tried `this.props.router.push({ query: { d } });`, but no luck.

So my question: **is there any way to change the router query without [triggering events](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents)** such as `routeChangeStart(url)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to just use the browser's API.

```js
refreshQuery(date) {
  const dateString = formatDate(date) // YYYY-MM-DD
  window.history.pushState('', '', `?d=${dateString}`)
}
```

This changes the date URL parameter when the user flips through the calendar, which can be snagged by `componentDidMount()` when the users refreshes/shares the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You can keep track of the previous pathname and do a conditional check in the `routeChangeStart` event handler to see if the pathname(without query) changes:

```
// _app.js

import Router from "next/router";

let previousPathname = null;

function handleRouteChange(url) {
  const pathname = url.split('?')[0];
  if (previousPathname && previousPathname !== pathname) {
    console.log(`App is changing from ${previousPathname} to ${pathname}...`);
  }
  previousPathname = pathname;
};

Router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);

...
```

This may not answer your question directly since it will still trigger `Router.events` but hopefully can help you with your use case.

Comment: With the caveat, that if you are inside a react component you will need to store `previousPathname` with `useRef`/`useState`. (`useRef` is probably better, won't trigger a re-render).

Comment: Right, and also you may want to unsubscribe from the event: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage-6

Answer (score 1):

Short version: you can't (at least AFAIK).

The first requirement to change the URL in the browser without reload the page is to do that in a single page application.

To achieve I'm afraid you need to drop `next/router` and start to use `react-router`, in this [article](https://dev.to/toomuchdesign/next-js-react-router-2kl8) you can find details about how to do a SPA with next using react router.

Once you have done, with `this.props.history.push("/new/url")` react router feature you can do what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using both `next/router` and `react-router` in one project? I've used the latter in previous project, but I like the features that `next/router` has, like pre-rendering links and page loading bars. I edited my question to specify my use case

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about drawbacks of using both the routers together, but I strongly suspect that prerendering and page loading (about the bar you like) are in contrast with single page application, which is a prerequisite for what you are looking for: if you don't want to reload the page you have to renounce the page loading bar...